# Column spanning in treectrl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm spanning some columns depending on the length of a string in treectrl and want to show the third column nearby the first column.

I created a tree-widget via tktreectrl.

Inside this, I created some columns:

(tree is the pathName of the tree-widget)

```
set columnID colItem
set columnID2 colzwei
set columnID3 coldrei
set columnID4 colvier
set columnID5 colfuenf
set columnID6 colsechs

$tree column create -expand no -weight 1 -text "Ergebnis:" -tags colItem -font $fontArr(font:12bold) -borderwidth 1
$tree column create -expand no -weight 4 -text "2" -tags colzwei -borderwidth 1 -font $fontArr(font:12bold) -uniform a -width 15
$tree column create -expand no -weight 4 -text "3" -tags coldrei -borderwidth 1 -font $fontArr(font:12bold) -uniform a 
$tree column create -expand no -weight 4 -text "4" -tags colvier -borderwidth 1 -font $fontArr(font:12bold) -uniform a -width 15
$tree column create -expand yes -weight 4 -text "5" -tags colfuenf -borderwidth 1 -font $fontArr(font:12bold) -uniform a 
$tree column create -expand yes -weight 4 -text "6" -tags colsechs -borderwidth 1 -font $fontArr(font:12bold) -uniform a
```

These columns should be filled with several data.

I'd like to have, that the spanning behaves differently depending on the length of the given text.

(txt1 and txt2 are given by another function and look like this:

txt 1: Grünland-Acker (GrA), Lehmiger Sand (lS), Bodenstufe (II), Wasserstufe (3), Klimastufe 7.9° - 7.0° C (b), Grünlandgrundzahl 33, Grünlandzahl 29

txt2: 1610 m²)

```
set itemID [$tree item create -button auto -tags $zel]
```

.
.
.

```
if {[string length $txt1] > 100} {
    $tree item span $itemID colItem 3
    $tree item span $itemID colfuenf [$tree column count]
} else {
    $tree item span $itemID coldrei [$tree column count]
}

Later I configure the text:
if {[string length $txt1] > 100} {
    $tree item style set $itemID $columnID styAny $columnID5 styAny
    $tree item text $itemID $columnID $txt1 $columnID5 $txt2
} else {
    $tree item style set $itemID $columnID styAny $columnID3 styAny
    $tree item text $itemID $columnID $txt1 $columnID3 $txt2
}
$tree item element configure $itemID $columnID elemTxtName -font [list $fontArr(font:12normal) {}] -justify right
```

The data in the third column (coldrei) are shown with some space if the part of the tree with long text is opened. If I close this part of the tree, the data in the third column are close to the first column (just the 15 pixels of the second row, as expected).
How can I get the third column near the first column, even if the tree part with long data is opened?

This is, how it looks with the part with long text opened (in this case, it's "Bodenschätzung")

[image]

And this is, how it looks with the Button "Bodenschätzung" closed.
[image]

So I want the other items to have always the same space between txt1 and txt2, regardless the button "Bodenschätzung" is opened or closed. How can I do that?